# node js convert pdf/docx from server to html for client

Tags: node.js

Currently writing a module to convert a docx/pdf file in nodejs from cloud to be editable from react js. Which is the best npm module to get the exact docx/pdf in same format.

Tried using mammoth js , but the format of the docx file completely changes and same goes for pdf2html converts that are available.

Answer (score 0):

you could try Hummus.js module --> https://www.npmjs.com/package/hummus .

it can be used to edit pdf documents.

Comment: I have used hummus for a different module to parse text. But what am looking for is to send the pdf/docx to the web UI to be editable and get it back and convert it back to pdf/docx. The problem is on converting into the HTML formal, all the alignment, font size disappears.

Answer (score -1):

I found mammoth to work well for me after doing a few things to make it work with react. Here is some example code:

```
import worddoc from './Folder/Document.docx'
const mammoth = require("mammoth");

class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      html: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let currentComponent = this;
      fetch(worddoc).then(res => res.arrayBuffer()).then(ab => 
        mammoth.convertToHtml({arrayBuffer: ab}).then(function(result){
        var html = result.value; 
        currentComponent.setState({html: html})
    })
    .done()
    )}
```

After doing this, I found that when i render the variable from state that I see html tags. To get formatting that I want from my doc and hide these tags I used dangerouslySetInnerHTML in my component render:

```
...
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:  this.state.html}} />
...
```

I hope this helps!